# Getting value in nested dictionary and list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Hello I'm trying to gain the number values from this kind of format:

```
{'Hello' : {'Values': [{'Number': 2, 'Name': 'John'},{'Number': 5, 'Name' : 'Bob'}, {'Number':7, 'Name' : 'Fred'}]}}
```

How will this be possible in python? I'm trying to get this output

```
[2,5,7]
```

and

```
['John', 'Bob', 'Fred']
```

Thank you very much.

So far I've tried to see how many times the `for` loop would run so I ran

`for i in dictionary_name['Hello']['Values']`

Comment: What have you tried? (Hint: look at list comprehensions.)

Comment: So far I've tried to see how many times the for loops would run so I ran

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {'Hello' : {'Values': [{'Number': 2, 'Name': 'John'},{'Number': 5, 'Name' : 'Bob'}, {'Number':7, 'Name' : 'Fred'}]}}

numbers = []
names = []

for val in dict['Hello']['Values']:
    numbers.append(val['Number'])
    names.append(val['Name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension :

```
my_dict = {'Hello' : {'Values': [{'Number': 2, 'Name': 'John'},{'Number': 5, 'Name' : 'Bob'}, {'Number':7, 'Name' : 'Fred'}]}}
numbers = [key['Number'] for key in my_dict['Hello']['Values']]
names = [key['Name'] for key in my_dict['Hello']['Values']]
```